# How to merge/combine two arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

How can I merge or combine two arrays in this order.

```
var list1 = ["A", "B", "C"];
var list2 = ["X", "Y", "Z"];

 var i = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < list1.length && list2.length; i++) {
     var list3[i] = list1[i] + list2[i];
 }
```

The final result would be.

```
var list3 = ["AX", "BY", "CZ"];
```

Comment: I guess you already have the right answer, right?

Comment: use map function

Comment: What if the arrays are unequal length then?

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz, if he needs to support old browsers, `map` won't work with IE8 and below.

Comment: @Rodrigo that would be a very weird case (usage of IE<11). But in that case, he would need to use a poly-fill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works fine, just need to declare `list3` before loop rather than inside it

```
var list1 = ["A", "B", "C"];
var list2 = ["X", "Y", "Z"];

var i = 0;
var list3 = []; //observe this line here
for (i = 0; i < list1.length && list2.length; i++) {
     list3[i] = list1[i] + list2[i]; //var is removed
}
```

**Edit**

Also observe the change in **for-loop condition** as well

```
for (i = 0; i < list1.length && i < list2.length; i++) { // i needs to be less than list2.length as well
     list3[i] = list1[i] + list2[i]; //var is removed
}
```

**Note**

- Above code will ensure that `list3` has the length of `Math.min (list1.length , list2.length)`

Answer (score 6):

You can use `map()` like this:

```js
let list1 = ["A", "B", "C"];
let list2 = ["X", "Y", "Z"];

let result = list1.map((c, i) => c + list2[i]);

console.log(result);
```

You can also use template literals:

```js
let list1 = ["A", "B", "C"];
let list2 = ["X", "Y", "Z"];

let result = list1.map((c, i) => `${c}${list2[i]}`);

console.log(result);
```

**Useful Resources:**

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Template Literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [`Arrow Functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 4):

If lengths are the same you can use `map()` method.

```js
var list1 = ["A", "B", "C"];
var list2 = ["X", "Y", "Z"];

const merged = list1.map((e, i) => e + list2[i]);
console.log(merged)
```

Answer (score 3):

You were almost there:

```
var list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
var list2 = ['X', 'Y', 'Z'];
var list3 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < list1.length; ++i) {
  list3[i] = list1[i] + list2[i];
}
```

Declare `list3` outside the loop. And since both lists have the same size, you need to check just one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function **[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**.

```js
var list1 = ["A", "B", "C"];
var list2 = ["X", "Y", "Z"];

var result = list1.map((e, i) => e + list2[i])

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Or, you can **[`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)** the arrays, check for the length, and concatenate the elements:

```js
var list1 = ["A", "B", "C"],
    list2 = ["X", "Y", "Z"],
    jump = list1.length, 
    result = [],
    arr = list1.concat(list2);
    
for (var i = 0; i < jump; i++) result.push(arr[i] + arr[i + jump]);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Bit of Syntax issues:

1. Declare `list3` as an empty array.
2. Don't use `var` to redeclare.

```js
var list1 = ["A", "B", "C"];
var list2 = ["X", "Y", "Z"];
var list3 = [];
var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
  list3[i] = list1[i] + list2[i];
}
console.log(list3);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare `list3` in advance and initialize with an empty array.

And you need to check if the index is smaller than the length of `list2` for getting only values at the same index for result.

```js
var list1 = ["A", "B", "C"],
    list2 = ["X", "Y", "Z"],
    list3 = [],
    i = 0;
    
for (i = 0; i < list1.length && i < list2.length; i++) {
    list3[i] = list1[i] + list2[i];
}

console.log(list3);
```